# Minimum Window Substring the time complexity of my solution

Tags: java, algorithm, time

Minimum Window Substring

this is a problem from Leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/

I found a solution based on Sliding Window Algorithm, but I cannot figure out the time complexity. Some people said it is O(N), but I think it is not. Please help me, thanks!

```
    public class Solution {
    // Minimum Window Algorithm, the algorithm must fit for specific problem, this problem is diff from ...words
    // 348ms
    public String minWindow(String s, String t) {
        int N = s.length(), M = t.length(), count = 0;
        String res = "";
        if (N < M || M == 0)    return res;
        int[] lib = new int[256], cur = new int[256];  // ASCII has 256 characters
        for (int i = 0; i < M; lib[t.charAt(i++)]++);  // count each characters in t
        for (int l = 0, r = 0; r < N; r++) {
            char c = s.charAt(r);
            if (lib[c] != 0) {
                cur[c]++;
                if (cur[c] <= lib[c])   count++;
                if (count == M) {
                    char tmp = s.charAt(l);
                    while (lib[tmp] == 0 || cur[tmp] > lib[tmp]) {
                        cur[tmp]--;
                        tmp = s.charAt(++l);
                    }
                    if (res.length() == 0 || r - l + 1 < res.length()) 
                        res = s.substring(l, r + 1);
                    count--;  // should add these three lines for the case cur[c] c is char in s but not the one visited
                    cur[s.charAt(l)]--;
                    l++;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
 }
```

Comment: In general longer more descriptive variable names would help the readability of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are N steps to add  every char in s to `r` position

There are no more than O(N) `while` operators - at most N working cycles with `++l` operations, and at most N worthless checks of `while` condition

So overall complexity is linear, if we don't take into consideration `s.substring`.

Note that substring operation should be moved out of the loop, we have to keep the best index pair only, and get substring at the very end.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the improvement is really brilliant, I have move the substring operation outside, and use left and right index to record the positions, then running time is faster, which is only around 300ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
check out my solution:

public class Solution {
    public String minWindow(String S, String T) {
        Map<Character, Integer> pattern = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        Map<Character, Integer> cur = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int begin = 0, end = 0;

        // fill in pattern by T
        for(int i = 0;i < T.length();i++) addToMap(pattern, T.charAt(i));

        // initialize current set
        for(int i = 0;i < T.length();i++) cur.put(T.charAt(i), 0);

        // go through S to match the pattern by minimum length
        for(int i = 0;i < S.length();i++){
            if(pattern.containsKey(S.charAt(i))){
                queue.add(i);
                addToMap(cur, S.charAt(i));
                // check if pattern is matched
                while(isMatch(pattern, cur)){  /* Important Code! */
                    if(i - queue.peek() < min){
                        min = i - queue.peek();
                        begin = queue.peek();
                        end = i+1;
                    }
                    cur.put(S.charAt(queue.peek()), cur.get(S.charAt(queue.peek()))-1);
                    queue.poll();
                }
            }
        }

        return end > begin?S.substring(begin, end):"";
    }

    private void addToMap(Map<Character, Integer> map, Character c){
        if(map.containsKey(c))
            map.put(c, map.get(c)+1);
        else
            map.put(c,1);
    }

    private boolean isMatch(Map<Character, Integer> p, Map<Character, Integer> cur){
        for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry: p.entrySet())
            if(cur.get((char)entry.getKey()) < (int)entry.getValue()) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```